How to partition a list and send requests in parallel
I would like to partition a list into a sublists, and send a request for each sublist in parallel.
I have a list of product ids, want to partition it to be sublists with the size of 3.
List<List<UUID>> productBatches = StreamSupport.stream(Iterables.partition(productIds, 3).spliterator(), true).toList();
List<ProductPriceResponse> productPrices = productBatches.parallelStream()
        .map(batch -> productPriceService.getProductsPrices(batch))
        .flatMap(List::stream)
        .toList();

Let's say I have 2 batches, but I tested in opensearch that the latter request is sent after the first one is returned.
List<String> list = new java.util.ArrayList<>(List.of());
for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
    list.add("test" + i);
}

List<List<String>> listBatches = StreamSupport.stream(Iterables.partition(list, 3).spliterator(), true).toList();

List<String> testStrings = listBatches.parallelStream()
    .map(batch -> {
        System.out.println("Batch: " + batch.toString());
        return String.join(",", batch);
    })
    .toList();

However, I wrote a test like below, and had conditional breakpoint to stop at "test3", it successfully printed all others strings in the list. I have no idea why the test can be processed in parallel while the implementation for product prices cannot

Try to print thread name Thread.currentThread().getName() for your implementation and see if requests are executed different fork-join threads.

From where do you get Iterables.partition? I do not find that in the Javadoc for Java 23.

(A) Your question is confusing and unclear, at least to me. I do not see the connection between your code at top and your code at bottom. I cannot decipher a specific technical question being asked. (B) This code is overwrought, overly complicated. This code could be rewritten to be much simpler, easier to read, and with more control than is possible with parallelStream. If that interests you, edit your Question to invite a rewrite.

How is productPriceService.getProductsPrices implemented? Does it perhaps have some locking, thereby only allowing a single request at a time? Possibly in a connection pool?
